# Postgres Table creation through Chef

Tags: postgresql, chef-infra

I've created a database in postgres using Chef, but I don't know how to create a table using that database. I've done it manually and everything is working fine. I want to execute it through Chef scripts.

This is what I was trying to do, for creating tables:

1. Create a createtable.sql file in say "ABC" cookbook
2. Create a path to the SQL file in the Chef cache.
   create_tables_script_path = File.join(Chef::Config[:file_cache_path], 'createtable.sql')
3. Write the SQL script to the filesystem:

   ```
   cookbook_file create_tables_script_path do
     source 'createtable.sql'
     owner 'root'
     group 'root'
     mode '0600'
   end
   ```

Is there any better way to create tables through recipes? Just a sample example is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `database` cookbook, it has custom resources for managing databases and DB users.

Comment: But my question is about creating table . I've already created database and user

Comment: Sorry, didn't read carefully enough. I don't recommend running migrations (including table creation) from Chef for the reasons mentioned at https://github.com/poise/application#database-migrations-and-chef

Comment: But I just want to create a simple table to test whether a table can be created or not .

Comment: require 'pg'
conn = PGconn.connect("",5432, "", "", "postgres")

conn.exec("create table rtest ( number integer default 0 );")
conn.exec("insert into rtest values ( 99 )")
res = conn.query("select * from rtest")

Comment: That is an option, but compiling the `pg` gem can be really error prone usually due to cross-linking difference versions of OpenSSL between Chef and the system libpq. We're planning to fix this at some point, but for now I would shell out to the `pq` command line via an `execute` resource.

Comment: Ok got your point .. So is there any way to create a table using chef .. Just a simple script needed to create a table . Please help me out on this

Comment: Can you give me a simple script to create via execute resource in postgres .. It is very urgent for me

Comment: `execute "psql -f whatever.sql"` will run whatever commands in that file, just normal Postgres command line stuff.

Comment: psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist comes up while trying to execute the below command :

Comment: postgresql_database 'Sonatadpost' do
  connection(
    :host      => '127.0.0.1',
    :port      => 5432,
    :username  => 'postgres',
    :password  => node['postgresql']['password']['postgres']
  )
  action :create
end

execute "psql -f createtable.sql"

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with how to use Postgres, that is way out of scope for StackOverflow. You can probably find a ton of tutorials on how to use `psql` but I can't explain it in a text box this small.

Comment: @PrabalDas As an option (even if it relies on pg gem), you can have a look at [`liquibase`](http://www.liquibase.org/) and riotgames's [cookbook](https://github.com/RiotGames/liquibase-cookbook) to use it. As coderanger said, you have to know what you're doing if you go this path. (little drawback, it will always set an updated resource as the liquibase execute command will always be run, it is still idempotent as liquibase itself check if it needs to do something or not)